# How to Remove Larger Padding Between Subsequent Elements Using CSS Only?

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible to remove the **smaller** padding between subsequent elements with CSS only?

I'm creating a section padding system for a website in which paddings are guaranteed to be consistent, while sections manage their own paddings.

The rules are:

- If two subsequent sections have the same padding, one gets cancelled
- If two subsequent sections with different padding occur, the **smaller** padding get's cancelled

```html
<body>
  <section data-section-padding="none" />
  <section data-section-padding="s" />
  <section data-section-padding="m" />
</body>
```

```scss
body {
    --section-padding-none: 0;
    --section-padding-s: 50px;
    --section-padding-m: 88px:

    [data-section-padding="s"] + [data-section-padding="s"],
    [data-section-padding="m"] + [data-section-padding="m"] {
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    [data-section-padding="s"] + [data-section-padding="m"] {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    [data-section-padding="m"] + [data-section-padding="s"] {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    ...
}

section {
    &[data-section-padding="none"] {
        padding-top: var(--section-padding-none);
        padding-bottom: var(--section-padding-none);
    }

    &[data-section-padding="s"] {
        padding-top: var(--section-padding-s);
        padding-bottom: var(--section-padding-s);
    }

    &[data-section-padding="m"] {
        padding-top: var(--section-padding-m);
        padding-bottom: var(--section-padding-m);
    }
}
```

### Edit

I've found a solution using the `+ selector` and `calc` (see below) but am curious if CSS selectors can provide a more scalable solution.

```scss
    [data-section-padding="s"] + [data-section-padding="s"],
    [data-section-padding="m"] + [data-section-padding="m"] {
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    [data-section-padding="s"] + [data-section-padding="m"] {
        padding-top: calc(var(--section-padding-m) - var(--section-padding-s));
    }

    [data-section-padding="m"] + [data-section-padding="s"] {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: none isn't a padding value, perhaps correct that first.

Comment: Also I think your understanding of selectors may  not be complete. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors to find out what the + in a CSS selector does.

Comment: @AHaworth good catch on the padding none but irrelevant to my question. 

I’m aware my knowledge on the limitations of combinators and separators is incomplete, hence why I’m posting a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think you'd need to use CSS :has which is not implemented by Firefox currently. Also, I am a little uncertain about the method in general. What if one of the elements has a background, or doesn't that matter?

Comment: The adjacent sibling combinator in `.foo + .bar` makes the rule select the second element, `.bar`. So you won't be able to use this for _"If two subsequent sections with different padding occur, the smaller padding get's cancelled"_, if the smaller padding is on the first of those two elements.